# Translating my cocos2d game into other languages

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have done a game in cocos2d. I used English. How do I translate that game to other languages like French, Japanese, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using cocos2d has anything to do with your question. You have to translate the text to all the different target languages, and if you don't know all the languages, find a translator.

Use google to find somewhere to hire a translator, if that's what it comes down to.

Comment: Alternatively if you're translations are minimal you could try using Google Translate (http://translate.google.com/)

Comment: How to bring Localisation in my game